# How to remove Application.DoEvents() with better solution like BackgroundWorker in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

This is my code. I am using Application.DoEvents() for waiting that UI thread is finished.

```
public override void Process(Crawler crawler, PropertyBag propertyBag)
{
    AspectF.Define.
    NotNull(crawler, "crawler").
    NotNull(propertyBag, "propertyBag");

    if (propertyBag.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return;

    if (!IsHtmlContent(propertyBag.ContentType))
        return;

    m_Logger.Verbose("CefGlue started for url {0}", propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString());

    CefGlueBrowserForm cefGlueBrowserForm = new CefGlueBrowserForm(propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString());
    cefGlueBrowserForm.Show();

    while (!cefGlueBrowserForm.Done)
        Application.DoEvents();

    string htmlSource = cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
    propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlSource));
    base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
}
```

I am reading that `Application.DoEvents()` is evil. I am also getting sometimes stackoverflow exception. What to use instead of `Application.DoEvents()`?

I try something with `BackgroundWorker` but nothing works

Example:

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!e.Cancel)
    {
        CefGlueBrowserForm cefGlueBrowserForm = new CefGlueBrowserForm(propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString());
        cefGlueBrowserForm.Show();

        while (!cefGlueBrowserForm.Done)
            Application.DoEvents();

        e.Result = cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
        cefGlueBrowserForm.Dispose();
        waitHandle.Set();
    }
};

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        string htmlSource = e.Result.ToString();
        propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlSource));
        base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
    };

bw.RunWorkerAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
waitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

What can I do?

EDIT:

added code how cefGlueBrowserForm.Done is set.

```
   public partial class CefGlueBrowserForm : Form
{

 public CefGlueBrowserForm(string url)
        {
            m_Logger = NCrawlerModule.Container.Resolve<ILog>();
            m_url = url;
            InitializeComponent();
            CefManager.InitializeCef();
            AddWebBrowser(m_url);
        }

private void AddWebBrowser(string startUrl)
        {
            m_textBox = new TextBox
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                ReadOnly = true,
            };
            m_textBox.Parent = this;
            Console.Box = m_textBox;

            Console.WriteLine("Loading URL ...");
            CefGlueBrowser = new ChromiumCefWebBrowser();
            CefGlueBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            CefGlueBrowser.BringToFront();
            CefGlueBrowser.StartUrl = startUrl;
            CefGlueBrowser.Parent = this;
            Controls.Add(CefGlueBrowser);
            Console.WriteLine("URL " + startUrl + " loaded.");

            CefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd += Browser_LoadEnd;
        }

private void Browser_LoadEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_Logger.Verbose("Page load was ended for url {0}", m_url);
            MyCefStringVisitor visitor = new MyCefStringVisitor(this, m_url);
            ((LoadEndEventArgs)e).Frame.Browser.GetMainFrame().GetSource(visitor);
        }


private class MyCefStringVisitor : CefStringVisitor
        {
            #region Instance Fields

            private CefGlueBrowserForm m_cefGlueBrowserForm;
            private string m_url;
            private ILog m_Logger;

            #endregion

            #region Constructors

            public MyCefStringVisitor(CefGlueBrowserForm cefGlueBrowserForm, string url)
            {
                m_Logger = NCrawlerModule.Container.Resolve<ILog>();
                m_cefGlueBrowserForm = cefGlueBrowserForm;
                m_url = url.NormalizeUrl();
            }

            #endregion

            #region Instance Methods

            protected override void Visit(string value)
            {
                string currentUrl = m_cefGlueBrowserForm.CefGlueBrowser.Browser.GetMainFrame().Url.NormalizeUrl();
                if (m_url.Equals(currentUrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || currentUrl.Contains(m_url))
                {
                    m_Logger.Verbose("Getting html source for url {0} and closing Event", m_url);
                    m_cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml = value;
                    m_cefGlueBrowserForm.Done = true;

                    m_cefGlueBrowserForm.CefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd -= m_cefGlueBrowserForm.Browser_LoadEnd;
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Proper way would be to decouple long running code in separate method and execute it as background tasks. But it's hard to see here where the long running code is and when and how is cefGlueBrowserForm.Done set? Why don't you simply use cefGlueBrowserForm.ShowDialog instead of Show? DoEvents is indeed "evil", you should remove it.

Comment: I modified my question. So you suggest completely remove DoEvents. But is hard because I ned to wait before Done is set.

Comment: Move the code you need to run into a seperate method, create an event in your GlueBrowerserForm and subscribe to it and run that method in its eventhandler or you can just uses ShowDialog instead of Show

Answer (score 3):

So what you want to do is execute the rest of the code after the form has been closed.  You can do that by simply subscribing to the `FormClosed` event and running the rest of that code there, rather than blocking the UI thread until the form is closed:

```
CefGlueBrowserForm cefGlueBrowserForm = 
    new CefGlueBrowserForm(propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString());
cefGlueBrowserForm.Show();

cefGlueBrowserForm.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
{
    string htmlSource = cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
    propertyBag.GetResponse = () => 
        new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlSource));
    base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
};
```

There's no need for other threads to do this.

Another approach is to leverage the `await` keyword to accomplish this same general task, but with a generally easier syntax.  If we take the time to write a simple helper method that generates a `Task` that will be completed when the form is closed:

```
public static Task WhenClosed(this Form form)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    FormClosedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, args) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        form.FormClosed -= handler;
    };
    form.FormClosed += handler;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then we can write the method like this:

```
public async Task Process(Crawler crawler, PropertyBag propertyBag)
{
    //...

    CefGlueBrowserForm cefGlueBrowserForm =
        new CefGlueBrowserForm(propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString());
    cefGlueBrowserForm.Show();

    await cefGlueBrowserForm.WhenClosed();

    string htmlSource = cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
    propertyBag.GetResponse = () =>
        new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlSource));
    base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
}
```

And while this *looks* like it's blocking until the form is closed, under the hood this is generating code that will act rather similarly to the code that we have above; it will run everything after the `await` as a continuation fired when the event fires.

Comment: Thank you for idea but isn't cefGlueBrowserForm after form is closed null because does not exist any more (disposed closure). And yes after I get html back I would like to do some extra work.

Comment: @mbrc No, it's not null, the form has been closed, and as a result trying to interact with certain aspects of it's UI won't succeed, but it certainly exists.  If you need to interact with its UI you can use `FormClosing` instead of `FormClosed`, in which case the event is fired just before the form will be closed.

Comment: I have tried and yes it is not null but form is closed before cefGlueBrowserForm.FormClosed is fired. The code is never executed. Process method is a thread and does nor wait until form is completely loaded...

Comment: @mbrc The code most certainly is executed.  Without knowing exactly what you're doing, or what is happening (i.e. what's not working), it's hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: When I call cefGlueBrowserForm.Show(); browser is opened and imidiatelly closed. Does not wait until Browser_LoadEnd is executed or efGlueBrowserForm.FormClosed is executed. I have used debugger and it is closed in a second...

Comment: @mbrc Then it would seem that you are closing it yourself when this method ends.  You shouldn't be doing that.  It's important that the method not block until the form is "done", but rather that the method return immediately.  The caller of the method should expect that behavior.  That is how asynchronous programming works.  If the caller needs to do something when this code finishes, there are a number of ways of addressing it.  The easiest is shown in my edit, in which the method can return as `Task` indicating when it is done.

Comment: that why i am using DoEvents that form is completed. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @mbrc Sure, there are lots of ways, you just won't be able to change *only* this method.  For it to function properly, the methods using it will need to change.  It needs to behave asynchronously, and these are two ways of doing that.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me which in your opinion?

Comment: @mbrc There's no really good way to say without knowing more about the context of your program.  The first option is shorter/easier in the scope of just this one method, but the second is somewhat more extensible and makes for easier integration of this method within other larger methods.  Use whichever you prefer.